# Modifying number of features in Merge tool each simulation run of ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, merge, parameters, model

I am relatively new to ModelBuilder and null in python. I want to include Merge tool in my model. However:

- at run 1, I want to **Merge** shapefiles **s1 and s2**
- at run 2, I want to
  **Merge** shapefiles **s1, s2 and s3**
- at run 3, I want to **Merge** shapefiles **s1, s2, s3 and s4** etc.

How can I include this to my modelbuilder model? I know how to make it manually, but how to make it in the model?

I can't just set the "Merge" as Parameter, and I don't see to option to make it via "Make Variable".

How the model looks like:
[image]

Exported python snippet :

```
arcpy.InfestationGradient("C:/Default.gdb/bb05","C:/Default.gdb/bb06","C:/Default.gdb/forest05","C:/infestGradient.gdb/buff_bb_t2","C:/infestGradient.gdb/buff_forest_t2","C://Default.gdb/bb05_Merge")
```

Comment: Can you convert the model to a python script? It might be easier in python.

Comment: What does this part of your model look like in a test model?

Comment: If I understand the question (and it is likely at this point that I do not), you may be able to do it with 3 different models but I don't think you can have a single model determine which run you are doing and select inputs accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @jbchurchill, tahts what I thougth... I used three models, where I used "merge" with 2 items, 3 items and 4 items, accordingly. I was just wondering, if it is possible to do it more automaticaly

Comment: this may help http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/using-feedback-in-iteration.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question, simply right click on the Merge tool and go to Make Variable > From Parameter > Input Datasets and then make that a Parameter. You probably need to delete the existing links to the Merge tool to see it.

Looking at your model is appears you have have added `BB year t1` then `S1` and `S2` as variables to the model then connected them to the Merge tool. Wrong way of doing it. Expose the Parameter as described above, this provides you with the interface for adding as many layers you wish. You could even partially fill it with your `BB year t1`.

Comment: Awesome !! I wonder why I always missed this option: Merge tool -> Make Variable > From Parameter > Input Datasets. Thank you !! :-D